# How does one calculate the Mean Geometric Chord in extended Trapezoid Wing?

Tags: wing, wing-sweep

The general formula to calulate MGC of a wing is given for a trapezoid in many books but there isn't an example showing how to calculate it for a wing shaped like the one below. I tried to solve individually for section 1 and section 2 and take the mean between those values but couldnt get the solution. I just want to derive a simple formula in case the wing looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the mean geometric chord, calculate wing area divided by span.

For the mean aerodynamic chord you integrate chord squared over span and divide the result by wing area.
$$l_\mu = \frac{\int^{+\frac{b}{2}}_{-\frac{b}{2}}l^2dy}{S}$$

Comment: So, what would be the $l^2$ for both of them combined be here?

Comment: @SherlockHomies l is the local chord. l² is local chord squared.